Flash Attention (flash_attn) Package Fails to Build Wheel in Google Colab Due to Subprocess-Exited-With-Error
I'm trying to run the Florence-2 model on Google Colab, which requires the flash_attn package. Previously, the model and package installed without any issues on Colab, but now I'm encountering the following error while trying to install flash_attn
Building wheels for collected packages: flash_attn
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Building wheel for flash_attn (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for flash_attn
  Running setup.py clean for flash_attn
Failed to build flash_attn
ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (flash_attn).

I’ve already tried the following but failed:

Upgrading pip, wheel, and setuptools

!pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools

2.Creating a virtual environment in Colab and installing flash_attn there
3.Looking for compatible versions of flash_attn and its dependencies, but haven't been able to pinpoint any version conflicts.
Since flash_attn is a critical dependency, I suspect there might be a version compatibility issue with recent Colab updates or underlying libraries, but I can't find any detailed version requirements or workarounds. Has anyone else faced this issue, or does anyone know the compatible versions or other solutions?
Thanks for any help on resolving this installation issue!

According to https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/34466#issuecomment-2442180500, you need to downgrade PyTorch 2.4 or it will take hours with 2.5
!pip install torch=='2.4.1+cu121' torchvision=='0.19.1+cu121' torchaudio=='2.4.1+cu121' --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu121

